# ldap_search_ext: Bad search filter (-7)

Tags: ldap

I got this output while trying to execute this ldapsearch command :

```
command:
ldapsearch -x -h xxxxx.com -p 389 -W -D "Administrator@xxx.com" -b "dc=xxx,dc=com" 
-s sub "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"


output:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=ntnx,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)((userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
# requesting: ALL
#

ldap_search_ext: Bad search filter (-7)
```

Can you help on this please. what is the issue here !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search filter is missing a closing parenthesis, should be :

```
"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))"
```